# Archive old directories and delete them

Tags: linux, bash, directory, archive, delete-file

How can we archive old directories and delete them after? If we suppose an old directory is one who has modified last time at least three days ago, I am able to get my directories list with

`find . -mindepth 2 -type d -mtime 3`

which return a list like

```
./dir1/1394547493
./dir2/1394525075
./dir2/1394531732
./dir3/1394546562
```

Now we need for any directory from this list to create a .ZIP archive in coresponding `dirX` containing ONLY the files from it (there are no more other directories in those directories), and delete the subdirectory right after. In the end our structure should look like this

```
./dir1/1394547493.zip
./dir2/1394525075.zip
./dir2/1394531732.zip
./dir3/1394546562.zip
```

Resulting archives must not contains any paths.

Comment: Are you familiar with http://unix.stackexchange.com?  You should also search there for relevant answers.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks for the tip. Google throw me here, it say nothing about unix.stackexchange.com. Good to know anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one-liner:

```
    for dir in $(find . -mindepth 2 -type d -mtime 3); do cd "$dir" && zip ../$(basename "$dir") * && cd - && rm -rf "$dir" || cd -; done
```

This one-liner enters each directory, zips its contents without parent directories and removes the directory on success, but leaving the directory in place in case of failure.

Good luck :)

Edit: Your directory names are required to not include spaces or tabs